# How can i rename multiple same occurrences in array

Tags: javascript

I want to rename my elements i have this array:

Rename multiple same occurrences in array

```js
var arr = ['a','b', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'r', 'b', 'a'];
let tally ={'a':0,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0,'f':0};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) != i) {
    tally[arr[i]]++;
    arr[i] = arr[i] + tally[arr[i]];
  }
}
console.log('arr', arr)
```

but i am getting a good result, i want this result:

```
'a', 'b', 'c' 'a1', 'f', 'r', 'b1', 'a2'
```

that is good, but how can i build this structure dinamic?

let tally ={'a':0,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0,'f':0};

**note: a, b,c is just for my example, actually are names of people in my proyect**

however if i have `var arr = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}, {name:'c'}, {name:'a'}, {name:'f'}, {name:'r'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'a'}]` also it could work?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there.. the tally[arr[i]]++ does not mean anything.. if you want to increase the number on the end, you have to have another object to tally the elements.. ex:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'r', 'b', 'a'];
var tally = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(!tally[arr[i]]) {
    tally[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
  else {
    tally[arr[i]] = tally[arr[i]] + 1;
    arr[i] = arr[i] + (tally[arr[i]] - 1);
  }
  console.log(tally);
}
console.log('arr', arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the tally to record counts for elements.  Map the array and append counts larger than one...

```js
const arr =  [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}, {name:'c'}, {name:'a'}, {name:'f'}, {name:'r'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'a'}];
let tally = {}
const result = arr.map(el => {
  const name = el.name;
  tally[name] = tally[name] ? tally[name]+1 : 1;
  return { name: tally[name] > 1 ? `${name}${tally[name]-1}` : name }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: for example if i have var arr = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}, {name:'c'}, {name:'a'}, {name:'f'}, {name:'r'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'a'}];

Comment: @display - sure.  Edited to illustrate the same idea except with an object.