# How can i remember name if already exist?

Tags: javascript

I have a collection called NEWS these are the new items I want to upload to my database, but if there are files with the same name in the COLLECTION collection, the name of the NEWS collection should be modified.

```js
const news = [{name:'one'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}]
const colection = [{name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name: 'two1'}, {name:'one1'}, {name:'four1'},{name: 'two2'}, {name:'one2'}]

let tally = {}
let updated = []
for (const el of news) {
  const name = el.name
  updated = news.map(el => {
    tally[name] = tally[name] ? tally[name] + 1 : 1
    el.standard_name =
      tally[name] > 1
        ? `${name}${tally[name] - 1}.${name}`
        : `${name}.${name}`

    return el
  })
}
console.log(updated)
```

if i have these collections:

```
const news = [{name:'one'}, {name:'one'}]

const colection = [{name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name: 'two1'}, {name:'one1'}, {name:'four1'},{name: 'two2'}, {name:'one2'}]
```

to first element: as there is already one named 'one' and 'one1' and 'one2' it should be named 'one3'.

to second element: as there is already one named 'one' and 'one1' and 'one2' and 'one3' it should be named 'one4'.

like this:
const news = [{name:'one3'}, {name:'one4'}]

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? If you can show your attempts, we can show how to fix them.

Comment: @iagowp i put my code

Comment: Can you distinguish from this earlier question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308823/how-can-i-rename-multiple-same-occurrences-in-array

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're looking for this.

The below code counts the number of elements in `colection` which starts with name of passed element `one` in this case. And if the count is greater than zero, it's added to end of name like `'one' + count` to make `one1`, `one2`, etc.

```js
const news = [{name:'one'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}]
const colection = [{name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name:'one1'}, {name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one2'}]

function addElement(new_item){
  const reps = colection.filter(elem => (elem.name.startsWith(new_item.name))).length
  colection.push({ name: new_item.name + (reps>0?reps:'') })
}

addElement(news[0])
addElement(news[2])
console.log(colection)
```

Refer the below code if you want to update the news array

```js
var news = [{name:'one'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name:'four'}]
const colection = [{name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name:'one1'}, {name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one2'}]

news = news.map( current => {
  reps = colection.filter(elem =>  elem.name.startsWith(current.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')) ).length
  if(reps) return current.name + reps
  else return current.name
} )

console.log(news)
```

Comment: I am not so sure if you wanted to update the `news` array or `colection` array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const news = [{name:'one'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}]
const colection = [{name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name:'one1'}, {name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one2'}]

let tally = {}

colection.forEach(el => {
   let name = el.name;
   let indexOfDigits = name.search("\\d+");
   name = indexOfDigits !== -1 ? name.substring(0, indexOfDigits) : name; 
   tally[name] = tally[name] ? tally[name]+1:1;
});

const updates = news.map(el => {
      const name = el.name;
      tally[name] = tally[name] ? tally[name] + 1 : 1
      el.standard_name =
        tally[name] > 1
          ? `${name}${tally[name]-1}`
          : `${name}`

      return el
    })
console.log(updates);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little convoluted, but it should do what you want:

```js
const news = [{name:'seven'}, {name:'one'}, {name:'one'},{name:'seven'}];

const col = [{name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name:'one1'}, {name:'four'},{name: 'two'}, {name:'one2'}, {name:'seven23'}].reduce((a,c)=>{
 let [k,n]=c.name.match(/(\D+)(\d+)?/).slice(1);
 (a[k]=a[k]||[])[n||0]=c;
 return a
},{});

news.forEach(e=>{
 let n=col[e.name]?.length||0;
 if (n) { // name exists: add number to name and add to array
  let o={...e}; o.name+=n;
  col[e.name][n]=o; 
 // name does not exist: start new array
 } else col[e.name]=[e];
})

console.log([].concat(...Object.values(col)).filter(e=>e))
```

I actually convert the original `colection` array into an object. The property-keys in this object are the non-numeric parts of the `name`-property if the original elements, the property-values are arrays collecting the individual elements starting with the same `name`.

Thus will simplify the merge process as I will be able to quickly find the right place.